# eclipse GEF DnD issue

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

I am facing a strange issue related to GEF based DnD in one of our RCP based application. I am trying to drag an item from a JFace based tree to another windows application (3rd party) and due to some reason it is not working. However if I drag and drop a SWT based table item it works and also the tree item can be dropped to notepad ot other such apps. We are facing issue only with that 3rd party app (no access to logs), what could be going wrong?

In a very high level code looks like below,

Listener added on tree view page

`treeviewer.addDropTargetListener(new TransferDropTargetListener(...));`

The listener
`public class TransferDragSourceListener extends AbstractTransferDragSourceListener {`

Data set

```
@Override
public void dragSetData(DragSourceEvent event) {
.... some code goes here and then I set the data...
event.data = someStringValue;
}
```

Comment: Maybe the `Transfer` your `getTransfer` returns is not supported, but this is just a guess.

Comment: @greg-449 - I do not see a not supported message, however I see two transfer objects as transfer agents in ```DragSource```, I am using ```TextTransfer```. The two transfer agents are  ```TextTransfer``` and ```TreeViewerTransfer```, can this be an issue?